# Batch file loop to grab all folders in a directory except for a certain folder

Tags: batch-file, cmd, directory

Just wondering the best way to do this in a single batch file.  I have a folder called C:\Program\Foo  and I want to grab all the folders except for the testing folder inside of foo, and I want to xcopy into D:\     so in D:\ foo will be there but no test folder.

Is there a way I can loop through each folder and check for a certain name not to include?

using /Exclude would mean I would need an extra text file with "Testing" in it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see why you could not create a temporary exclusion file (using a temporary folder, that is):

```
@ECHO OFF
FOR %%F IN ("%TEMP%\exclude.txt") DO SET tmpf=%%~sF
ECHO Testing>%tmpf%\exclude.txt
XCOPY source destination /EXCLUDE:%tmpf%\exclude.txt other options
```

**Note:** `XCOPY` does not recognise double quotes as path delimiters in the `/EXCLUDE` option and offers no alternative for specifying paths with spaces, which can be a problem on Windows XP systems. This limitation can be worked around by replacing the original path with its counterpart consisting only of short names. That is what the `FOR` loop in the above script does for the `%TEMP%` folder.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use `ROBOCOPY`?

```
ROBOCOPY C:\Program\Foo D:\ * /E /XD Test
```

- `/E` copies subfolders and files
- `/XD` excludes directories

Answer (score 0):

Use the EXCLUDE option and put your exclusions in that file. That will let you exclude entire directories.

http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/using-xcopy-backup-can-exclude-some-directories-t489674.html

xcopy "c:\document and settings" "i:\documents and settings\" /s /d /EXCLUDE:c:\a.txt

a.txt contains

\temp\
\temporary internet files\

You may need to use shorter DOS file names.